# Cannot install Haskell package stream-fusion-0.1.2.5: Ambiguous occurence

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, stream-fusion

I'm trying to build the project [Barbarosa](https://github.com/nionita/Barbarossa) which requires the package [stream-fusion-0.1.2.5](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion). However `cabal install` fails with the following

```
[3 of 3] Compiling Control.Monad.Stream ( Control/Monad/Stream.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-8bb5b9c9/build/Control/Monad/Stream.o )

Control/Monad/Stream.hs:136:10:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘MonadPlus’
    It could refer to either ‘Control.Monad.Stream.MonadPlus’,
                            defined at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:124:1
                          or ‘GHC.Base.MonadPlus’,
                            imported from ‘GHC.Base’ at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:80:1-15

Control/Monad/Stream.hs:140:10:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘MonadPlus’
    It could refer to either ‘Control.Monad.Stream.MonadPlus’,
                            defined at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:124:1
                          or ‘GHC.Base.MonadPlus’,
                          imported from ‘GHC.Base’ at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:80:1-15
```

I'm using GHC version 7.10.2 on OS X 10.11, installed via Haskell Platform.

It seems that the only dependency of `stream-fusion` is `base` whose version should be fine, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: That package's `Control.Monad.Stream` module defines its own `MonadPlus` typeclass. I think the package has simply bitrotten.

Comment: I suspect `GHC.Base` didn't use to export `MonadPlus`, but things were shuffled around by the 7.10 changes.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get things to compile by replacing the three occurrences of

```
import Data.List.Stream
```

with:

```
import Data.List
```

and removing `stream-fusion` from the `build-depends:` section of the cabal file.